# How to pass multi value parameter in ssrs 2005 URL and how to save report directly to excel

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have develop one ssrs 2005 report.
My first question is How to pass multi-value parameter in ssrs report URL. For Example simple parameter passing to report url is worked fine for me .
http://MYSERVER/ReportServer?MyReport&rs:Command=Render&QuestionName=Q1
but how to pass muli values for the same parameter like
http://MYSERVER/ReportServer?MyReport&rs:Command=Render&QuestionName=Q1,Q2,Q3 etc

I tried it this way like 
http://MYSERVER/ReportServer?MyReport&rs:Command=Render&QuestionName=Q1&QuestionName=Q2&QuestionName=Q3 but when I execute the report it took only the first parameter value that is "Q1"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one solution of my own question.
 Create one dataset that shows question names and then set it to multivalue parameter in the report. This way when you will use parameter in the ssrs report url like 
 
http://MYSERVER/ReportServer?MyReport&rs:Command=Render&QuestionName=Q1&QuestionName=Q2&QuestionName=Q3
then it will work.